# Could anyone please explain my jquery ajax issue here?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I am sorry if I am asking for too much. I tried to read on the web about ajax but still did not get it how to implement it to my project. Could anyone please explain it for a noob like me? I have a separate javascript file with this function.

```
$('#treeTab').bind(
    'tree.select',
    function(event) {
        if (event.node) {
            // node was selected
            var node = event.node;
            var selectedIndex = queuesArr.indexOf(node.name);

            //alert(node.name);
        }
        else {
            // event.node is null
            // a node was deselected
            // e.previous_node contains the deselected node
        }
    }
);
```

I need to pass selectedIndex value to my jsp scriptlet. 
I think that I should put this in my javascript inside

```
function(event) { 
    if (event.node) { }
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp", { name: selectedIndex });
}
```

and this in asp file

```
<%
    dim fname
    fname = Request.Form("name")
    Response.Write(fname)
%>
```

But how to get the value in jsp scriptlet and use it in java method?

Comment: What jsp scriptlet? All you've got here is Javascript and ASP. Javascript is NOT Java. There is no real relation.

Comment: @developerwjk, thank you for your reply. But please don't think that I am that stupid. I can tell the difference between javascript and java. So I don't understand your comment above. I have jsp scriptlet AND separate javascript file I have java method in jsp scriptlet and I need to pass the integer variable from javascript to jsp scriptlet to use it in jsp scriptlet. Two different files. So I don't know which code to put inside jsp scriptlet and which code to put inside javascript. I have an uncommon situation here. So I did not find anything on it on the web.

Comment: If you have a jsp involved you didn't post any of it, nor does it seem likely you would have both ASP and JSP involved. There's something big here you aren't explaining about what you're doing. Are you trying to communicate between two webservers, one ASP and one JSP, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation for jquery's $.post method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). The method takes these parameters:

> jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )

So, basically, in your `$.post` call you need to add either a Javascript function name or Javascript function declaration:

Option 1:

```
$.post("demo_test_post.asp", 
   { name: selectedIndex }, 
   function(data){ alert(data); } 
);
```

Option 2:

```
function msgData(data){ alert(data); }
$.post("demo_test_post.asp", 
   { name: selectedIndex }, 
   msgData(data)
);
```

You also need to understand that Java/JSP and Javascript are not related. This is all Javascript not JSP scriptlets.